# How to compare function objects

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I compare if two function objects hold the same function reference?

```
struct A {
    void b(){}
}
int main() {
    A a;
    auto f1 = std::bind(&A::b, a);
    auto f2 = std::bind(&A::b, a);

    f1 == f2 // ???
}
```

Comment: What error do you get from this?

Comment: You can, to a certain degree, compare `std::function` objects (via `function::target`). However, this doesn't work portably for `std::bind`-expressions, as their type is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `std::bind` guarantees only to be callable and to have member type `result_type`. There is no standard-conformant way to compare binded functions.

> **Return value**
>
> A function object of unspecified type T, for which
>   std::is_bind_expression::value == true, and which can be stored in
>   std::function. The object is movable if f and all args are movable,
>   and is copyable otherwise. The type defines the following members:

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind